# Can normal be converted to Hardcore, or vice versa?

Tags: diablo-iii

Once finishing the game, and unlocking Hardcore, is it possible to convert your initial character into a Hardcore state?

Conversely, if you create a Hardcore character, but decide that you would rather it just be a normal one, is this conversion possible?

Answer (score 8):

No, it is not possible to convert characters between Normal and Hardcore modes other than reusing the name and class and levelling a new one (which isn't really re-using).